# Answering Amen to Kaddish when you don't know where they are holding

Tags: halacha, kaddish, amen

It says in SA OC Siman 124 Sif 11 that one may answer Amen to a bracha even if they didn't hear the bracha (only because they know the bracha is being said and as long as they know *which* bracha is being said.)

What about in Kaddish. Must someone know to which "Amen" they are answering to of Kaddish in order to answer Amen. Or may one say Amen as long as they know the Kaddish is being said and hear when everyone else is answering?

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for certain for kaddish, but for sure for brachos the mishnah berurah quotes a machlokes  and writes that one should not say amein if unsure the bracha.

Comment: Where is that MB?